# How to formulate an XPATH expression for an attribute that contains a certain string?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

[image]

I have several tool tip elements in my HTML with the same class name. I am trying to print the tool tip message for the element I am highlighting. The only attribute that changes when mouse is pointed on that sepcific element is the "opacity: 1". This particluar attribute changes from "0" to "1" when the mouse is pointed.

I wrote the following Xpath that gives me several elements as see the above picture but I would like to access the element that has "oapcity: 1" in the "style" attribute.

```
("//div[@class='d3-tip bar-chart n']")
```

can someone please help me formulate an xpath for the above?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this XPath:

```
//div[@class = 'd3-tip bar-chart n' 
    and contains(normalize-space(@style), 'opacity:1')]
```